# Webdriverjs - find length of content within div in test

Tags: javascript, webdriver, protractor, cucumberjs

I am using Protractor wrapped around webdriverjs and I have this function finding the element I search for:

```
ptor.findElement(protractor.By.css('.rightPanel')).then(
      function(el) {
        if(el.length > 0){
                    ptor.switchTo().defaultContent();
                    callback();
                }else{
                    callback.fail("side panel is empty");
                }
      });
```

I know that el.length is does not work. Anyone has any suggestion on how I can make sure that within my div there is some content using Webdriverjs? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about the [getInnerHtml()](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getInnerHtml) function?

```
ptor.findElement(protractor.By.css('.rightPanel')).then(
  function(el) {
    el.getInnerHtml().then(
      function(html) {
        if(html.length > 0){
          ptor.switchTo().defaultContent();
          callback();
        }else{
          callback.fail("side panel is empty");
        }
      });
  });
```

If that's too temperamental you could instead try the [getText()](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getText) function.